# How to incease transaction log manually in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server

in my sql 2005 , 10 MB of disk space will be allocated for transaction logs.

I wand to incease this 10MB to more ... Where is the option for increase this size manually in sql 2005?

hoping ur response,

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server Management Studio

- Right click on your Database and select **Properties**
- Select the **Files** page
- You should now be presented with a table view showing your Data File and Log File
- Click on the Log File in the list (normally second in list)
- You should be able to change the **Initial Size (MB)** to an additional 10MB
- Clicking OK at the bottom should save your changes (you can check this by repeating the first few steps)

Comment: That table is blank,
i use add button to add datafile, but the problem is file type is "Data" only , there is no Log File

Comment: When you add a new file, you should be able to change the 'File Type' to Log, as well as changing the logical name, filegroup and Initial Size. If you still having problems make sure you have the correct SQL Permissions to do this. eg. being part of the db_owner role